can a TTL index delete a document currently locked inside a long running transaction?
A TTL index is applied to a mongodb collection. It is instructed to delete documents after expiration if A = true.
A document of this collection is currently locked inside a long running transaction. The document exceeds the TTL while in transaction. The value for A before the start of the transaction was true. When the transaction started, the value of A was modified to be false.
Hence, after the transaction is completed and the locked is removed on this document, then A = false.
Will this document be removed by the TTL after the transaction completes?

Why do you care? If the document is not deleted, then it will be deleted at next TTL worker job a few minutes later. And why do you attempt to modify a document which is going to be deleted in the next minutes? Review your application design.

That sounds like a race condition.
When the TTL worker runs, it will scan the index, and delete expired documents.
Assuming that A = true is a partial index filter, if the document has already been modified by a transaction, but the transaction has not yet committed, there are 2 possibilities:

The TTL delete will encounter a write conflict and the document will not be deleted.  When the transaction completes, the document will no longer be in the TTL index, so it will not be considered again.
The transaction will abort with a write conflict and the document will be deleted.

If the TTL run reaches the document before the transaction modifies it, the document will be deleted, and there are again 2 possibilies, depending on how the update is done inside the transaction:

The transaction aborts with write conflict as before
The update operation doesn't find a matching document, and succeeds without making any modifications, and the transaction is able to succeed.

